# Two strings are not equal in node js, but look equal to me

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand what's happening. I work in node js, here is my code snippet:

```
var body = Buffer.concat(responseBody).toString();
var expectBody = fs.readFileSync(expectfile);
if(expectBody != body) {
    console.log("Response body != expected file");
    console.log("Response body: " + body);
    console.log("Expected body: " + expectBody);
}
```

And here is the output I am seeing:

```
Response body != expected file
Response body: {"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]}
Expected body: {"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]}
```

As far as I can see, the strings are identical, but node js thinks otherwise.

I took the printed strings and saved them into two files, then did a diff - got nothing!

Does this have something to do with the way the files are read?

As far as I understand, != is for non-strict comparison, so should only check the actual text in the variables, right?

=== update: ===

Following your suggestions, I tried this:

```
if(JSON.stringify(expectBody) != JSON.stringify(body)) {
       console.log(" stringify, not equal!");
}
```

and

```
if(expectBody.toString() != body.toString()) {
    console.log(" to string, not equal!");
}
```

I'm still getting "stringify, not equal" and "to string, not equal" printed out :(

===== solved: ======

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
var filecheck = require('./file_checks.js');
var expectjson = JSON.parse(expectBody);
var receivedjson = JSON.parse(body);
if(filecheck.jsonCompareSync(expectjson, receivedjson)) {
    // not equal
}
```

Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: Compare the length of the strings.

Comment: @Teemu I do this before this check with if(expectBody.size == body.size), and this returns true.

Comment: Then check the type of the "operands".

Comment: stringify the both value before compare.

Comment: go through each character and compare them one by one. I suppose it because of whitespace with different codes.

Comment: you should be checking length not size of the strings.

Comment: @Asgeirr I'm not sure if this is relevant. If the length is the same, it doesn't mean the contents are. I need to check if the contents are the same.

Comment: That's true, but the size of a string is undefined. If the size isn't undefined you're prpobably dealing with objects and not strings. Try doing a .toString() on expectedBody in the comparison.

Comment: How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/6568620

Comment: @Asgeirr I tried doing if(expectBody.toString() != body.toString()) {, got the same result :(

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that internally JavaScript has two different approaches for validating equality.

The latest ECMAScript standard defines seven data types:

Six data types that are primitives:

- Boolean
- Null
- Undefined
- Number
- String
- Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)

and then there is a data type as

- Object

**Primitives are compared by their value, while objects are compared by their reference.**

example 01

```
let a = { "one":"a"};
let b = { "one":"a"};
console.log(a!=b);//true
```

example 02

```
let a = { "one":"a"};
let b = a;
console.log(a!=b);//false
```

In your case you are comparing Objects then you will have to

- Convert object into primitive(string) and then compare

or

- Write a separate deep object comparison function(you could find lot of them with simple google search)

#### UPDATE - test script for your case

```
let a = {"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]};
let b = {"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]};

console.log(a!=b); //true
console.log(JSON.stringify(b) != JSON.stringify(b)); //false



// Some other approach to make sure you are not fooled by your eye comparison
var crypto = require('crypto');
console.log(crypto.createHash('md5').update(a).digest("hex"));
console.log(crypto.createHash('md5').update(b).digest("hex"));
```

Comment: I've added more detail to the original question. I tried converting into string, doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: thanks I found the solution. Put it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is.

```
let obj1 = JSON.stringify({"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]});
let obj2 = JSON.stringify({"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]});
```

and then compare them, `obj1 != obj2`

So like this

```
var body = Buffer.concat(responseBody).toString();
var expectBody = fs.readFileSync(expectfile);
if(JSON.stringify(expectBody) != JSON.stringify(body)) {
  console.log("Response body != expected file");
  console.log("Response body: " + body);
  console.log("Expected body: " + expectBody);
}
```

Note this will fail if the order of object is not same.

Comment: But I am not trying to do ===, I'm doing !=, this is the opposite of ==, isn't it?

Comment: sorry, i have updated my answer, the problem with object comparison in object is that it is shallow, so convert them into a string and compare the strings. Is this helpful..?

Comment: I added:
let obj1 = body;
let obj2 = expectBody;
if (obj1 != obj2) {
  console.log("Still not equal!");
}

I get "Still not equal" printed :(

Comment: convert both of those objects into string using `JSON.stringify` like in the code I shared above, and then perform the comparison.

Comment: The values are inside a file I receive, I can't hard-code them.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work :)

```js
var a = {"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]}

var b = {"version":1,"jobs":[{"asset_id":"asset_1","status":"queued","status_info":null}]}


// check your condition

if( JSON.stringify(a) !=  JSON.stringify(b)){
   console.log("Objects are different")
}else{
   console.log("objects are same")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I added:
if(JSON.stringify(expectBody) != JSON.stringify(body)) {
  console.log(" stringify, not equal!");
}
And still getting " stringify, not equal!" printed out :(

Comment: did you checked the expectBody and body , having any diff or its same in the question

Comment: can't check them directly, as they are var, not files. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue with 2 strings that are the same letter by letter after rendered to screen, but they are slightly different byte by byte.

By creating hash they are really different, so in test case I have to implement a customized `stringEquals` instead of using `assert.equal`.

// Buffer.from(stringA).toString('hex')

```
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
```

// Buffer.from(stringB).toString('hex')

```
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
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
var filecheck = require('./file_checks.js');
var expectjson = JSON.parse(expectBody);
var receivedjson = JSON.parse(body);
if(filecheck.jsonCompareSync(expectjson, receivedjson)) {
    // not equal
}
```

Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: hope to see the content of your `file_checks.js`.specially the function `jsonCompareSync`

Comment: @Nuwan oh sorry didn't realise this wasn't a standard library. Had another look, it basically checks all values one by one.